# Loop through multidimensional JSON Array and get values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've created a JSON object which has two arrays in it. I've searched all over the web on how to extract the data but all the code I've tried has either returned "undefined" or [object object].

Can you please look at my example and show me how I would do this?

```
<html>
 <head>
     <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="NPP-Plugin">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="file"></div>
 <div id="applicID"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var IETMObj = {
    "allItems": [{ 
         "sFile": "Test.html",
         "Applicability": [{   // second dimension
                            "ApplicID": "subj_1",
                            "ApplicDisp": "Driving",
                            "Condition": "In rain"
                    },{
                            "ApplicID": "subj_2",
                            "ApplicDisp": "Running",
                            "Condition": "Uphill"
                    }]
            }]
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < IETMObj.length; i++){
      document.write("<br><br>array index: " + i);
  var obj = IETMObj[i];
  for (var key in obj){
    var value = obj[key];
    document.write("<br> - " + key + ": " + value);
  }
}


  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `IETMObj` is an object, not an array.

Comment: The array you want to process is `IETMObj.allItems[0].Applicability`

Comment: @Barmar I'm afraid I couldn't get your correction to the code working. http://js.do/MHammett/multidimensionalobj And I looked at the other questions, and tried their solutions. They didn't work in my case. Which is why I reached out for help.

Comment: Try `var applicability = IETMObj.allItems[0].Applicability;` then loop through `applicability` the way you're looping through `IETMObj` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`ITEMObj` is an object, not an array. The array you want to loop through is `IETMObj.allItems[0].Applicability`.

```
var applicability = IETMObj.allItems[0].Applicability;
for (var i = 0; i < applicability.length; i++) {
    document.write("<br><br>array index: " + i);
    var obj = applicability[i];
    for (var key in obj){
        var value = obj[key];
        document.write("<br> - " + key + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

And if there can be more than one item in `allItems`, you should have an outer loop for them.